# Config laravel mix to build specific vue app when component files change

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

My Laravel project with multiple Vue.js applications. The project directory structure is as follows:

```java
├── public
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app_the_first.js
│   │   ├── app_the_second.js
├── resources
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── the_first_components
│   │   │   │   ├── // Vue component files
│   │   │   ├── the_second_components
│   │   │   │   ├── // Vue component files
│   │   │   ├── app_the_first.js
│   │   │   ├── app_the_second.js
│   ├── sass
│   │   ├── app_the_first.js
│   │   ├── app_the_second.js
├── views
│   ├── the_first.blade.php
│   ├── the_second.blade.php
├── package.json
├── webpack.mix.js
```

when I change `the_first_component` and run `npm run dev/prod`, both `app_the_first.js` and `app_the_second.js` are re-build

My `webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/assets/js/app_the_first.js', 'public/js').vue()
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_the_first.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app_the_second.js', 'public/js').vue()
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_the_second.scss', 'public/css');
```

I want to rebuild the `app_the_first.js`  only, not rebuild the `app_the_second.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Mix does not natively support building selected assets out of the box because running `npm run` dev or `npm run prod` will trigger all tasks defined in `webpack.mix.js`. You can define an environment variable to specify which app you want to build:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const appName = process.env.APP_NAME;

if (!appName || appName === 'the_first') {
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app_the_first.js', 'public/js').vue()
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_the_first.scss', 'public/css');
}

if (!appName || appName === 'the_second') {
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app_the_second.js', 'public/js').vue()
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_the_second.scss', 'public/css');
}
```

Then, you can use an environment variable when running your npm scripts to specify which app to compile:

```
APP_NAME=the_first npm run dev

APP_NAME=the_second npm run dev

npm run dev
```

modify your package.json scripts to include these new commands:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run development",
  "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
  "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
  "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "prod": "npm run production",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "dev-first": "cross-env APP_NAME=the_first npm run dev",
  "prod-first": "cross-env APP_NAME=the_first npm run production",
  "dev-second": "cross-env APP_NAME=the_second npm run dev",
  "prod-second": "cross-env APP_NAME=the_second npm run production"
},
```

Now you can use npm run dev-first to only compile the assets for the first app, and npm run dev-second for the second app.

If you don’t have cross-env installed, you can install it with:

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```